# PHP Foreach loop with a single element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a function that parses the 'entry's in a nested array:

```
$data = Array(
   [date] => 'date'
   [entry] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
         [Title] => 'title0'
         [Price] => 'price0'
      )
      [1] => Array(
         [Title] => 'title1'
         [Price] => 'price1'
      )
   )
 )
```

Looping through this with a `foreach($data['entry'] as $entry){` works great if there is more than one entry. However, it there is only one entry I am served:

```
 $data = Array(
   [date] => 'date'
   [entry] => Array(
      [Title] => 'title'
      [Price] => 'price'
   )
 )
```

And the foreach loop fails.

Is there an elegant way to write a foreach that will grab each entry[0], entry[1] sub array (like normal) or back off one level if there is only one entry and grab the entire 'entry' array instead?

---

Addendum: the stuff I'm doing on the entries is pretty involved... I supposed I could separate that out into a different function, do an if(is_array) check then call the function once, or for each... but that seems inelegant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you don't need the $temp variable step.

```
$data['entry'] = isset($data['entry'][0]) ? $data['entry'] : array($data['entry']);
```

Comment: nice -- and much more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The best elegant way is to create an array based on keys even if there is just one.

Like this:

```
$data = Array(
   [date] => 'date'
   [entry] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
         [Title] => 'title0'
         [Price] => 'price0'
      )
   )
 )
```

Comment: Agreed, however I don't have control over how the single-entry data is served to me... is there an easy way to nudge it into one if it isn't already?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you defined a multi-dimensional array like this struct:

`entry = array(array())`

in 2nd case you only declared `entry = array()`

think about:

`if(is_array(entry[0]))`
...

Comment: Yes, which is precisely my point... if(is_array) is a workaround but not elegant (as I already pointed out in my addendum).

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!isset($data['entry']['0'])){
    $temp = $data['entry'];
    unset($data['entry']);
    $data['entry']['0'] = $temp;
 }
 foreach($data['entry'] as $entry) ...
```

Not quite "elegant" but it works...

Answer (score 0):

try this it work for me

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_numeric($key)) {
            //not multidimensional
                 $data1 = $data;                    
            } else {                   
                 $data1 = $value;
            }
            //do your stuff
            echo $data1;                        
}
```

eventualy you can make a recursive function